# Pannellum clickHandlerFunc

Tags: javascript, pannellum

I am trying to use the clickHandlerFunc to open a Modal box. I am getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: a.clickHandlerFunc is not a function at HTMLDivElement. (pannellum.js:68)"

The following is my codes:

```
"hotSpots": [
                    {

                        "pitch": 1.60311491347256,
                        "yaw": 22.349004691308146,
                        "type": "scene",
                        "text": '',
                        "sceneId": "",
                        "clickHandlerFunc": "openModal"
                    },


function openModal() {
        $(".popup-overlay, .popup-content").addClass("active");
    }
```

How can I resolve the problem? I need to open a modal box when the hotspot is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following out...

first define the function you wish to call before the call to pannellum, for example..

```
var openModal=function(){alert("hello")};
```

Then the line for the click handler should be...

```
"clickHandlerFunc": openModal
```

i.e. without the quotes.

Substitute the alert("hello") for whatever function call or code that you like.